# How to use .map to add a new property to an array of objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

trying to use underscore.map to iterate over array of objects and add a boolean property to each object based on if the object value passes a truth statement.

```
var desserts = [
  {
    name: 'Chocolate Cake',
    ingredients: ['cocoa', 'flour', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'milk', 'butter' ],
    type: 'cake'
  },
  {
    name: 'Snickerdoodles',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cinnamon', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cookie'
  },
```

etc..

Heres what I have -

```
var glutenFree = function (desserts) {
  return _.map(desserts, function(dessert) {
    if (dessert.ingredients.includes('flour')) {
      return dessert.glutenFree = 'false';
    } else {
      return dessert.glutenFree = 'true';
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: What do you want to know? is there is an error in your code?

Comment: @connexo Yes you can, an assignment without `cont`, `let` or `var` can be used as an expression. Which resolves into the value you assign. `someVariable = "foobar"` will resolve into `"foobar"`, so `return dessert.glutenFree = 'false'` will return `'false'`. Though the behaviour is not what OP wants, it is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the properties. Then return the element in the map function, so it gets added to the array.

```
var glutenFree = function (desserts) {
  return _.map(desserts, function(dessert) {
    if (dessert.ingredients.includes('flour')) {
      dessert.glutenFree = 'false';
      return dessert;
    } else {
     dessert.glutenFree = 'true';
     return dessert;
    }
  });
};
```

Though I'd make some adjustments.

- Instead of the string values `'true'` and `'false'`, you can use the boolean values `true` and `false`.
- You don't need to use the word "function", you can use lambda format instead
- `var` is rarely used nowadays, use `let` or `const` instead.
- If you only use the `if-else` statement to assign stuff, you can also use the ternary operator `<condition> ? <statement> : <statement>`

```
const glutenFree = (desserts) => {
  return _.map(desserts, (dessert) => {
    dessert.glutenFee = dessert.ingredients.includes('flour')
      ? false
      : true;
    return dessert;
  });
};
```

Of course, `dessert.ingredients.includes('flour')` itself is also a boolean value that is either true or false. So you could make the function even shorter by using the boolean value of this statement. If it includes flower, it is not gluten-free. So add a `!` in front to negate the boolean:

```
const glutenFree = (desserts) => {
  return _.map(desserts, (dessert) => {
    dessert.glutenFee = !dessert.ingredients.includes('flour');
    return dessert;
  });
};
```

Comment: Note that there is no reason to use `_.map()` if you are going to mutate the array elements. You should either use `_.forEach()`, in which case `desserts` holds the results. Or you should return a new object from `_.map()`, this prevents the `desserts` from being changed.

Answer (score 6):

No library needed:

```js
const desserts = [{
    name: 'Chocolate Cake',
    ingredients: ['cocoa', 'flour', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'milk', 'butter'],
    type: 'cake'
  },
  {
    name: 'Snickerdoodles',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cinnamon', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cookie'
  }
];

const dessertsExtended = desserts.map(dessert => ({ ...dessert,
  glutenfree: !dessert.ingredients.includes('flour')
}));

console.log(dessertsExtended);
```

Answer (score 1):

The map creates a new array with the value that you pass in the return statement. In your case, `return dessert.glutenFree = 'false';` is considered just as false, and return dessert.glutenFree = 'true'; is considered as true. Resulting in a array with just `['false', 'false']`.

To return the whole object, you need to modify it and then return the whole object, here's the refactored function:

```
var glutenFree = function (desserts) {
  return desserts.map(function(dessert) {
    if (dessert.ingredients.includes('flour')) {
      dessert.glutenFree = 'false'; // modifying the object
    } else {
      dessert.glutenFree = 'true'; // modifying the object
    }

    return dessert; // returning the whole object
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[The answer by connexo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74091367/how-to-use-map-to-add-a-new-property-to-an-array-of-objects#74091410) is essentially correct; it does not modify the input array. Also, you should use actual booleans (`true` and `false`) instead of strings that look like booleans (`'true'` and `'false'`).

However, connexo's answer does not use Underscore, as originally asked. Using Underscore has a small cost (your application grows by 8 kB), but it also has some benefits:

- Underscore runs everywhere. While functions like `map` and `includes` and other features such as spread syntax are nowadays part of the language, they are not universally available. Depending on where your application needs to run, this often means you will be using transpilation and polyfills, which tend to inflate the size of your application much more than Underscore.
- Underscore has some additional tricks compared to the standardized functions, such as [iteratee shorthands](https://underscorejs.org/#iteratee) and being able to iterate over plain objects. These can come in handy elsewhere in your application.

For these two reasons, I actually tend to use Underscore wherever I can. By exploiting the library to the max, you get maximum bang-for-bucks for those modest 8 kB of library.

Below is an Underscore-ified version of connexo's solution.

```js
const desserts = [{
    name: 'Chocolate Cake',
    ingredients: ['cocoa', 'flour', 'sugar', 'eggs', 'milk', 'butter'],
    type: 'cake'
  },
  {
    name: 'Snickerdoodles',
    ingredients: ['flour', 'milk', 'butter', 'eggs', 'sugar', 'cinnamon', 'cream of tartar'],
    type: 'cookie'
  }
];

const dessertsExtended = _.map(desserts, function(dessert) {
    return _.defaults({
        glutenfree: !_.contains(dessert.ingredients, 'flour')
    }, dessert);
});

console.log(dessertsExtended);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```